# PHCachingImageManager - Cache Location and File Name

Tags: ios, phasset

I need to pass the file location and name of an Asset I saved using PHCachingImageManager over to my web server.

I cannot see anything in the documentation on how and where to retrieve this.

I am using

```
self.imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];

[self.imageManager startCachingImagesForAssets:assetResult targetSize:targetSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:imageRequestOptions];
```

I can retrieve an image

```
[self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                     targetSize:mySize
                                    contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                        options:nil
                                  resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                      cell.imageView.image = result;
                                  }];
```

But I do not know how to get the actual Cache Details

Answer (score 0):

PHCachingImageManager works behind the scenes. There are now dedicated methods to access or list its content.
The whole purpose of the PHCachingImageManager is that requests to PHImageManager can be answered immidiately, if the requested asset has been changed.